# Android Service - Cant seem to find an example

Tags: android

I have scoured the web, I can't seem to figure out how to make an Android service actually DO anything.  I have found lots of examples of how to create a basic one, but none of the examples seem to show how to call the service from an activity, and have the service do something.

For example, I would like to have a service running that will send a TCP text message to a server when requested.  I can make the service, and have it run, but how the heck do I have the Activity make the call that passes a string to the method in the service that will send the TCP message?

This seems like it should be somewhat easy, but I just can't figure out, or find an example, of how to do it.  Maybe I am not understanding what a service should be used for?  I definitely want it running for a long period of time, no gui needed, and "service" requests to send TCP messages....hum...

Comment: Just as a point of clarification (this is something that it took me a while to understand), the concept of "Service" on the Android is not like Windows service, which runs in the background without a head.  It's more like a background worker thread, you create it and tell it to do its work, then it can fire an event when it's done.

Answer (score 1):

> I can make the service, and have it run, but how the heck do I have the Activity make the call that passes a
>   string to the method in the service that will send the TCP message?

Use the local binding pattern. In [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/), an activity binds to a service, in order to get some data retrieved by that service (weather forecast) based on a location change. In [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/18-LocalService/), an activity binds to a service to register a listener object to be notified of changes in a user's identi.ca timeline.

Or, use an `IntentService` and `startService()` to send a command to be processed by the `IntentService`. In [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteServiceUnbound/), I implement an `IntentService` that executes a BeanShell script supplied by a caller. In [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClientUnbound/), I implement an activity that sends the BeanShell script to the `IntentService`. This pair of examples is designed to demonstrate using this technique across applications, but the approach works fine within a single application as well.

> I definitely want it running for a long period of time

[No you don't](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/).

Comment: If you are just learning I would stick with the intent API and leave the binding pattern alone, it is a lot more difficult to understand, and leaves you constantly checking if your reference to your service is null.  IntentService is a good place to start http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html